# Fetchsize for large result

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I'm using the Datastax Java driver and have a partition key that has around 750000 items that I'd like to iterate over. I currently hit a ReadTimeoutException. Will setting `Statement#setFetchSize(2000)` be all I need to do to avoid the timeout (assuming I have memory in my client, that is)? Or will I need to do the paging myself manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the driver with protocol v2 or higher, this should be all you need. Automatic paging will occur under the hood, returning up to 2000 rows at a time.